# rememberLauncherForActivityResult don't call onResult

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, google-oauth

I'm trying to create simple one touch login with Google. I looked up a lot of questions, but nothing really worked. `onResult` just not called. However, I found out that the overridden `onActivityResult` is called. What may cause the problem with `rememberLauncherForActivityResult`?

How I starting the launcher:

```kotlin
    var authStarted by remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }

    val activity = LocalContext.current.findActivity()
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = GoogleSignInContract(),
        onResult = { it ->
            if (it == null) return@rememberLauncherForActivityResult
            it.addOnSuccessListener {
                if (it.idToken == null) return@addOnSuccessListener
                FBAuth.firebaseAuthWithGoogle(activity, it.idToken!!)
            }
        })
    if (authStarted) {
        SideEffect {
            launcher.launch(AUTH_CODE)
            authStarted = false
        }
    }
```

The contract:

```kotlin
class GoogleSignInContract : ActivityResultContract<Int, Task<GoogleSignInAccount>?>() {
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Int): Intent {
        val client =
            GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, FBAuth.newGsi(context.getString(R.string.web_oauth)))
        return client.signInIntent
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Task<GoogleSignInAccount>? {
        Log.d("GoogleSignInContract", "Result code: $resultCode")
        return when (resultCode) {
            Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent)
            }

            else -> {
                null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Flag noHistory didn't do anything***